# Getting Div's to align side by side in narrow browser

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGhEe/

I've read several tutorials and they all say use float or use relative positioning, but all the techniques I try aren't giving me expected results. This is a pretty simple thing to do, but I want to do it the "correct" way since using html tables is punishable by death. Any help?

If I use float left it stacks unnecessarily when the browser gets narrow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using float and you want it to show side-by-side, you need to set the width and make sure the sum of the widths are less than the width of the container, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/wks5b/).

Comment: Ok. This made me notice how I am centering the message div is incorrect. What about that?

Comment: I have width:50% in an attempt to center the page, but its more to the right if I make the browser narrow

Comment: @Dave: add `word-wrap: break-word;` to .normalText to allow the browser to add linebreak within words, or set a min-width on #message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your browser fit it all of the browser. Make your browser fluid.

i.e. Give % while defining the width of the layout.